# Avoiding loading spaCy data in each subprocess when multiprocessing

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, spacy

I would like to use spaCy in a program which is currently implemented with multiprocessing. Specifically I am using `ProcessingPool` to spawn 4 subprocesses which then go off and do their merry tasks.

To use spaCy (specifically for POS tagging), I need to invoke `spacy.load('en')`, which is an expensive call (takes ~10 seconds). If I am to load this object within each subprocess then it will take ~40 seconds, as they are all reading from the same location. This is annoyingly long.

But I cannot figure out a way to get them to share the object which is being loaded. This object cannot be pickled, which means (as far as I know):

1. It cannot be passed into the `Pool.map` call
2. It cannot be stored and used by a `Manager` instance to then be shared amongst the processes

What can I do?

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.5.2, on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't how you use `Pool.map` exactly but be aware that `Pool.map` doesn't work with a massive number of input. In Python 3.6, it's implemented in [Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l255) as you can see, it states it takes an `iterable` as first argument but the implementation does [consume the whole iterable](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l343) before running the multiprocess map. So I think that's not `Pool.map` that you need to use if you need to process a lot of data. Maybe `Pool.imap` and `Pool.imap_unordered` can work.

About your actual issue. I have a solution that doesn't involve `Pool.map` and works kind of a like *multiprocess `foreach`*.

First you need to inherit `Pool` and create a worker process:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process


class Worker(Process):

    english = spacy.load('en')

    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        for args in iter(self.queue.get, None):
            # process args here, you can use self.
```

You prepare the pool of processus like that:

```
queue = Queue()
workers = list()
for _ in range(cpu_count()):  # minus one if the main processus is CPU intensive
    worker = Worker(queue)
    workers.append(worker)
    worker.start()
```

Then you can feed the pool via `queue`:

```
for args in iterable:
    queue.put(args)
```

`iterable` is the list of arguments that you pass to the workers. The above code will push the content of `iterable` as fast as it can. Basically, if the worker is slow enough, almost all the iterable will be pushed to the queue before the workers have finished their job. That's why the *content of the iterable must fit into memory*.

If the workers arguments (aka. `iterable`) can't fit into memory you must synchronize somehow the main processus and the workers...

At the end make sure to call the following:

```
for worker in workers:
    queue.put(None)

for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```